Generation of the eletromagnetic wave or electric current by the photo-excitation
Suppose there is an incident photo with a specific frequency hitting the material; the incident photo is absorbed by this material. Meanwhile, the material is excited by this incident photo and generates another radiation electromagnetic wave with another specific frequency or generates an electric current.
Is there any way to describe this phenomenon, such as a formula with the green function method?
Thank you in advance.

It sounds like you're describing how a laser or the detector in a spectrometer works... would that be a fair comparison?

@isolated matrix Thank you for your reply. I am actually studying how to describe the response of the material to the laser stimuli. It is different from the mechanism how laser or spectrometer functions. I found a paper (Daniel E. Parker, et al. Diagrammatic approach to nonlinear optical response with application to Weyl semimetals, Phys. Rev. B 99, 045121 2019) online but it discusses the response of the material with special topological nontrivial property.

@isolated matrix I am looking for the method discussing the general materials without any special property. If you know any paper, would you please recommend it to me? Thank you.

There's this, but I'm not sure it's what you're looking for: https://escholarship.org/uc/item/3qz5k931
